# Gimp: can´t edit image due to "GEGL-Error"

Tags: gimp, gegl

Gimp(2.10 on Windows) is throwing a "GEGL-error" when i try to edit an image.
Some minutes ago i was able to edit a image with Gimp, but out of the sudden, Gimp is refusing every editing, claiming that

> This operation has no editable properties

??

[image]

What is going on?

regards

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your full screen with all of the relevant GIMP interface visible?

Comment: Oh, and consider to do that on a stack that is suitable for usage questions, e.g. SuperUser, instead of one for programming?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had the same problem after gimp 2.10 first install on ubuntu, and was surprised that I couldnt find similar problem reports in web, only one: [GEGL](http://%20https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152153/gimp-2-10-12-question).
The solution is rather easy: Select any selection tool before trying to select something.